# node.js - making result available globally (Request module)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to process the returned JSON result from the request
so I need to expand its scope outside this request call.
To do that I declared `data` variable with an empty string and assign the result to this `data` but it doesn't print the result.

How can I accomplish this?

```
module.exports = function(callback) {

    var request = require("request")
    var url = "http://sheetsu.com/apis/94dc0db4"
    var data = "";

    request({
        url: url,
        json: true
    }, function (error, response, body) {

        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            callback(body)

            data = body;

        }
    })

    console.log(data);


}
```

Comment: The `console.log(data)` actually runs before the callback, thus the data is empty. What is your final goal, what problem are you solving that needs data exposed like that?

Comment: I need to filter data and handle them differently. So if data is within category A, I need to run a different function. I wanna make those data ready within this module so it's ready to be used in route file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is executed in this order:

1. `request()` is executed
2. `console.log(data)`
3. `request()` callback function, where you asign `data` a value

If you want to print `data`, you must do it inside the request callback function. The [async](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/async) module, is very useful when performing async tasks, specially if you need to perform tasks in a specific order and use the data from this requests.

Answer (score 2):

This is classic async confusion : your `console.log` call will happen before the http request callback.

Comment: So in that case, how do I make this data contain the result and make it available outside the request call?

Comment: It is available outside the request call, but not when you call `console.log`.

Comment: As Marcos explained, your request callback will be executed after the `console.log` call. You should google about 'async javascript' if you don't understand the order of execution. Next, you have many ways to make `data` available outside your request, the first and obvious one is to use the actual `callback` function. Another way is to use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Promise)